# Get changes from one Branch in Git

Tags: git

I have my branch where i finished the work: `feature/my-branch`. This branch is created from `develop`
Somebody from my team updated the `develop` branch. Now i want to add my changes from `feature/my-branch` in `develop`, but when i create the pull request i have some conflicts between these 2 branches.
I want to get the changes from `develop` and to add them in `feature/my-branch`, to solve the conflicts and after that to merge the changes in `develop`. Doing this now i got in the `PR` the changes from `develop` plus the changes from my branch. 
Question: How to proceed in the above situation to avoid adding the changes from `develop` to `feature/my-branch` and when i will merge my branch in develop to not have the changes from develop just the changes from my feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your feature branch compatible with all the new stuff on develop branch. If there are conflicts, you need to solve them no matter which you choose.

You have two options to do so:

*Either* Merge the develop branch into your feature branch

```
git checkout feature/my-branch
git merge develop
// resolve conflicts
```

*Or* Rebase your feature branch onto develop

```
git checkout feature/my-branch
git rebase develop
// resolve conflicts
```

Afterwards: merge your features into develop

```
git checkout develop
git merge feature/my-branch
```

Comment: could you please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71657393/git-add-a-usage and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71658921/git-add-only-modified-files